# Como tener un arreglo e iterarlo con un tamaño long (java)

Tags: java, array

Tengo un arreglo que necesito iterarlo con un tamaño superior al que almacena `int`  pero me da error ya que el arreglo solo permite parametro `int`

```
    public class Prueba {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String cadena[] = in.readLine().split(" ");
                for (long i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(cadena[i]);
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: Es un tanto descabellado lo que quieres intentar. El proceso de iterar un valor que supere a lo que int puede proporcionar significa mucha carga, no tiene sentido que Java te permita iterar con long y lo mismo para almacenar un numero de datos que supere el int y meterlo en tu vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pides no es posible. La [documentación oficial de Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) para 10.4 es bastante clara:

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may
>   also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary
>   numeric promotion ([§5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)) and become int values.
>
> An attempt to access an array component with a long index value
>   results in a compile-time error.

Mi traducción libre sería:

> Los arreglos **deben** tener índices con valores enteros; se pueden 
>   utilizar como indices valores `short`, `byte` o `char` gracias a 
>   que son sujetos de una promoción de tipo numérico ([§5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)) 
>   y se convierten en valores enteros.
>
> El intento de acceder a un elemento de un arreglo con un índice de 
>   valor long resulta en un error en tiempo de compilación

El error será algo como:

```
test.java:12: possible loss of precision
found   : long
required: int
        System.out.println(array[index]);
                                 ^
1 error
```

Si por cualquier razón tienes un índice almacenado como long, lo que debes hacer es aplicarle un molde de tipo entero. No se puede crear un arreglo lo suficientemente grande que no pueda ser indexado por un entero en java, por lo mismo, no hay necesidad de utilizar tipos más allá de `int`.